# Difference in web page on localhost and host server

Tags: php, html

I have simple html page with php as given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Articles 'n' More::Articles</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="Articles, Management , english, computers, sharepoint, wp7, bio technology, nano technology, c#">
<meta name="keywords" content="Articles, Management , english, computers, sharepoint, wp7, bio technology, nano technology, c#">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr id="header" >
                <td height="30%" width="100%" colspan="3">
<?php include("Header.php"); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="body">
                <td width="15%" valign="top" align="left">
                    <table width="100%" border="3"  align="left">
                        <tr ><td>
<?php include("LeftPanel.php"); ?>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td  width="75%" valign="top">
                    <!--Articles-->
                    <?php 
                        $articlePerPage="10";
                        $subcatID = $_GET['subcatid'];
                        $curPageId = $_GET['pageId'];
                        $nextPageId=$curPageId+1;
                        $prevPageId=$curPageId-1;
                        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
                                if(!$con)
                                {
                                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                                }       

                                mysql_select_db("articles_db",$con);

                                $query="";
                                $queryCount="";

                                if($subcatID == "0")
                                {
                                $queryCount="select count(1) total from tbl_articles";
                                //echo "QueryCount is".$queryCount;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                $queryCount="select count(1) total from tbl_articles where SUBCATEGORY_ID=".$subcatID;                              
                                }
                                $resultCount= mysql_query($queryCount);
                                $rowCount = mysql_fetch_array($resultCount);
                                $totlaArticles= $rowCount['total'] ;
                                //echo 'total articles'.$totlaArticles;

                                if($subcatID == "0")
                                {
                                    $query="select * from (SELECT ARTICLE_ID,TITLE,CONTENT,POSTED_ON,POSTED_BY FROM TBL_Articles order by POSTED_ON desc limit ".$articlePerPage*$curPageId.") sub order by POSTED_ON asc limit ".$articlePerPage;
                                    //echo $query;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $query="select * from (SELECT ARTICLE_ID,TITLE,CONTENT,POSTED_ON,POSTED_BY FROM TBL_Articles where SUBCATEGORY_ID=".$subcatID."  order by POSTED_ON desc limit ".$articlePerPage*$curPageId.") sub order by POSTED_ON asc limit ".$articlePerPage;
                                }
                                $result = mysql_query($query);
                    ?>

                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr id="repeatingRow" valign="top">
                            <td width="100%">
                            <?php 

                                     $count=0;
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                  {
                                  $id= $row['ARTICLE_ID'] ;
                                  $title= $row['TITLE'] ;
                                  $content= $row['CONTENT'] ;
$count=$count+1;
                                  if(strlen($content)< 110)
                                        {
                                            $content=substr($content,0,strlen($content));
                                        }
                                        else
                                            {
                                        $content=substr($content,0,100);
                                        }
                                    $postedon=$row['POSTED_ON'] ;
                                    $author = $row['POSTED_BY'] ;

                            ?>

                                <table width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="100%" colspan="3">
            <a href="ShowArticle.php?articleid= <?php echo $id ; ?>&title=<?php echo $title ; ?>"><?php echo $title ; ?></a></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr >
                                    <h6>
                                        <td width="30%" align="left"><img src="Images/account.png" /><?php echo $author ; ?></td>
                                        <td width="30%" align="left"><img src="Images/clock.png" /><?php echo $postedon ; ?></td>
                                        <td width="40%" align="left"><img src="Images/folder.png" />General</td>
                                        </h6>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%" colspan="3"><br/><?php echo $content ;?><br />
                                        <hr  color="#49a6e1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                                                             </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                        <b>
                            <?php
                            //echo $subcatID;
                            //echo ("<a href='Articles.php?subcatid=".$subcatID."&pageId=".$prevPageId."'>Previous</a>");
                                if($curPageId>1)
                                {
                                    echo ("<a href='Articles.php?subcatid=".$subcatID."&pageId=".$prevPageId."'>Previous</a>");
                                    //echo ("<a href='Articles.php'>Previous</a>");
                                }
                            ?>
                        </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <b>
                            <?php
                                if($totlaArticles/($curPageId*10)>1)
                                {
                                    echo ("<a href='Articles.php?subcatid=".$subcatID."&pageId=".$nextPageId."'>Next</a>");
                                    //echo "<a href='Articles.php?subcatid='".echo $subcatID."@pageId= ".$nextPageId.">Next</a>"
                                }
                            ?>
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td height="65%" width="10%" valign="center">
                    <!--Right panel-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="footer" bgcolor="dfdfdf">
                <td height="5%" colspan="3">
            count is :  <?php echo $count;  include("Footer.php"); ?>
      <!-- do not get this part when upload on server -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This page gives the desired result when i try it on my local machine.
But when i upload it to my host server, i face following problems:

1. It shows only First 3(no scroll bar on webpage) articles in the article section where as on my local machine it shows all the article with a scroll bar.
2. Does not include footer.php
3. does not display the background color set in
4. I tried to set border for the table but it does not display any border

[hosted site on the server](http://articlesnmore.in/Articles.php?subcatid=0&pageId=1)

on my local machine i have XAMPP (Basispaket) version 1.7.4 with php 5.3.5 and on server i have Version 5.2.6 (run as CGI application)

Does any one has idea about why i am facing this problm and what could be the possible solution.

Comment: Lots of things could be causing this. Have you checked your server's PHP error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out.
The problem the content stored in database, it contained some code and some xml to be displayed on the web page.
so i just used these two lines

```
<?php 
$content=htmlentities($content);
echo "<pre><code>".$content."</code></pre>" 
?>
```

and it worked fine.

for the background colors i used style and now it working.

Answer (score 1):

Markup look weird and I found error message at the bottom:

```
Failed loading D:\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll
Failed loading D:\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_4.4.dll
```

---

Ok, I think that problem in files, that you include (`LeftPanel.php`, for example).
Why it contains this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
```

When you include this - markup breaks.

Comment: I find the problem the content part of the displayed last on screen contains some code  <Style x:Key=PivotStyle1 TargetType=controls:Pivot>
      <Setter Property=Margin Value=0/>
      <Setter Property=Padding Value=0/>
      <Setter Property=Foreground Value={StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}/>
      <Setter Property=Background Value=Transparent/>
      <Setter Property=ItemsPanel>
       <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
Because when i removed this part everything works f9
what can i do for it

Answer (score 1):

The footer.php issue might be connected to a capitalization issue. Is the php file have the first letter capitalized? Some servers will take exception if it's not exactly right.